# Is a worker can pickup more than one job?

Tags: laravel, queue, jobs, supervisord

I'm making a system that needs to process a lot of data. So I separate 30 jobs which are doing same function but different data. I'm wondering how the workers and jobs are doing. I'm using `larvel 6 and supervisor`. When I set `numprocs=1` and I check on jobs table, I see `9 of 30 jobs have attempts=1`. If so I think 9 jobs are picked up by 1 workers. When I set `numprocs=2`, I see `10 of 30 jobs have attempts=1`. Even if a worker runs 9 jobs, if I have 2 workers, it should `18 of 30 jobs have attempts=1`, isn't it?
**So is it not one worker runs one job?**
This is my supervisor config.

```
[program:laravel-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=/bin/php /var/www/test-dir/artisan queue:work --sleep=2 --timeout=3000 --daemon
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=nginx
numprocs=2
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/www/test-dir/worker.log
stopwaitsecs=3600
```

Comment: It was my fault. Old 8 workers were not killed somehow and the were still running. That's why 9 jobs are running while I have only one worker.

Answer (score 0):

You can use different job queues for different types of jobs you may have. See how to do that [here](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queues#customizing-the-queue-and-connection) - Laravel Docs about queues.

[Here](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queues#supervisor-configuration) is the documentation about configuring Supervisor. `numprocs` option just tells the server how much queue workers to run. You can maybe try to set up multiple laravel workers and combine that with different queues, but all in all, I think there is not much you can do to speed things up. At the end, laravel's queue worker is just a process that runs on your system. Hence, it can depend on system specs if it can run parallel.

There is no fixed number of jobs one queue will do. The queue will process everything that is in jobs table. If the job is a success, it will delete it from jobs table, if not, it will move it to failed jobs.

Comment: It seems like your answer couldn't cover my question. What I would like to know is that one queue can run multiple jobs at the same time or not. But it was my fault. Another 8 workers are still running on my server and that's why I'm doubting that.

Comment: One queue runs jobs one by one, reading them from the database or any other driver you've set up your queue to work on.